# How to redefine object variable in local scope

Tags: javascript, object, variables, scope

How can I redefine an object variable locally? With a normal variable, I would use `let` inside the function, but `let` doesn't seem to work with object variables. Is there a way?

The code below shows that I can redefine the variable globally by using `options.soundFileName = 'audio/60.wav';`. But it doesn't work if I use `let options.soundFileName = 'audio/60.wav';`.

```js
var options = {
  soundFileName: 'audio/01.wav',
};          
           
(function masterStart() {
  setInterval(function () {
  console.log('sound name global: ' + options.soundFileName)
   }, 1000);
}());

A();
function A() {
  options.soundFileName = 'audio/60.wav'; 
  // redefines sound file but globally
  // how can i redefinie it only within `A()`?
  
 }

/*
B();
function B() {
  let options.soundFileName = 'audio/60.wav'; // doesn't work at all
  
 }
 */
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*redefine an object variable locally*"? Like a copy/clone of `options`?

Comment: Variables work the same way no matter what type of value they contain.

Comment: `options.sounfFileName` is not a variable. `options` is a variable, `soundFileName` is a property of the object that it refers to.

Comment: I may be using the wrong terminology, but I want to define the sound file that functions use globally in an options object, but then within certain functions, I want to change the sound file that is used. However, I still want the code within each function to simply reference `options.foo` That way I won't have to make the variable names for each function unique. I thought I could do this with `let` but it doesn't work and throws an error.

Comment: The `setInterval` function takes  optional arguments after the timeout in milliseconds. Pass-in your config there.

Comment: @Barmar, that's interesting that `options.soundFileName` is not a variable and `options` is. That makes. So is there a way that I can target that property to change it locally? I'm not sure what the code syntax would be.

Comment: Have you seen the answer I posted several minutes ago?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, the answer just posted. I'll give it a try now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as local properties, only local variables.

If you want to make a temporary change to an object property, save the old value in a local variable:

```
function A() {
    let oldFileName = options.soundFileName;
    options.soundFileName = 'audio/60.wav';
    // do stuff
    // ...
    options.soundFileName = oldFileName;
}
```

Comment: No matter where I place `options.soundFileName = oldFileName;` it plays the oldFileName instead of the new one (`'audio/60.wav'`). I would think that as long as `options.soundFileName = oldFileName;` was at the end of function `A();` that it would run function `A()` using the new sound before returning `options.soundFileName` back to `oldFileName`, but it simply plays the `oldFileName`. Maybe some delays I'm using are causing an issue? I'll keep tinkering and let you know if I get it working.

Comment: I just saw that you're printing the value in an interval function. The interval function doesn't run until JavaScript returns, so the property will be set back to the previous value. It will never see the temporary value because JavaScript is single-threaded.

Comment: You will only see the temporary value in code that's actually run in the `do stuff` part of `A()`.

Comment: I can get your code working when I put `options.soundFileName = oldFileName;` in a `setTimeout` with a delay. E.g., `setTimeout(function () {options.soundFileName = oldFileName;}, 30);`. This isn't ideal because I have lots of functions firing that might (and seem to) use another functions `soundFileName` if they run at the same time. But it does prove that your code/idea works. I think the reason your code won't work with out the delay is that resetting `soundFileName` causes the old file to reset at the same time (or close enought). Is there a way to isolate these temporary changes better?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, two functions can't run at the same time. So it's not clear what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why are you using a global variable, instead of passing an options structure to each function?

Comment: I know that it's single threaded, but I'm not so sure what the limits of that are. I was hoping that even though only one fucntion can run at a time, maybe it would create a cue that would execute each chunck of code correctly, still. LIke, if another function is being executed, the next would wait in line to execute after.

Comment: I am using global variables because I have one function that is used by many other functions. The functions need to use/define variables inside the shared function. For example, the shared function takes a paramater `soundFileName`. I'd like each of the other functinos to be able to send it's unique `soundFileName`s to the shared function. I'm not sure how else I can do that besides redefining the global variable?

Comment: Asynchronous functions are queued, synchronous code simply executes directly. Asynchronous code doesn't run until all the synchronous code is finished.

Comment: So why don't the other functions just call `sharedFunction(mySoundFileName)`, and the shared function uses the parameter variable.

Comment: Ah, I think calling `sharedFunction(mySoundFileName)` is what I was missing! I'll try to implement that.